# Python path added to $PATH -- cannot find origin

Tags: terminal, python, path

I just installed Python 3.6 from [python.org](http://python.org/downloads/release/python-360/) on macOS Sierra.

Somehow, the path to python's `bin` is added to my every `$PATH` but I can't figure out how:

```
22:15 : echo $PATH                                                                          
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin
```

Now, `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin` is the default value in my `/etc/paths` and the `X11`, `git` and `TeX` parts come from the 3 files in `/etc/paths.d/`. But I have no Python-related file in `/etc/paths.d/`.

And there is nothing related to Python in my `~/.zshrc`.

Does anyone know where the Python bit of `$PATH` is coming from?

Comment: hat is in  ~/.zprofile and  ~/.zlogin and does this PATH show in a new shell? and what is in ~/.bashrc

Comment: What are the results of `cd; grep 'PATH' .z*`?

Comment: @Mark: bingo, Python modified (actually created) ~/.zprofile!! If you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Files.html#Startup_002fShutdown-Files) reads from up to 4files on start up

> If ZDOTDIR is not set, then the value of HOME is used; this is the usual case.

```
$ZDOTDIR/.zshenv
$ZDOTDIR/.zprofile
$ZDOTDIR/.zshrc
$ZDOTDIR/.zlogin
```

You need to look in all of them.

.zshrc is read every time a shell or sub shell is started.
.zprofile is read when you start a login shell - ie the first shell you start through terminal, and this is where I would put the PATH changes

Answer (score -1):

Check ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile

Comment: `.bash_profile` (`.bashrc` isn't common on macOS) is specific to Bash; the OP appears to be using Zsh.

Comment: Last time I had the same issue, I found I sourced bashrc in zshrc

Comment: @aahung zsh and bash languages differ .bashrc might cause syntax erros - much better to keep them separate

Comment: You made a point. It was long time ago I did this when I was not familiar and chased convenience. And recently I notice when I installed a new version of Python, the installer append to bash-files instead of zsh-files. Maybe he/she has the similar situation